# Error while installing truffle using npm install -g truffle on mac

Tags: npm, installation, terminal, truffle

I tried installing truffle on my mac but I always get this error, I have installed python and npm as well what should I do ?

I even googled and made a new folder or directory to install global packages (I'm lost)

[this is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ydl8.jpg)